# Guest Login to Microsoft Dynamics NAV ERP

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I am a newbie to **NAV** and I want to see how **NAV standard** tables (Item,Customer...) and Columns look like. I dont don't want to install the software now. Is there any way to get a online guest login for NAV ERP?

FYI, I have **SQL SERVER 2012** installed on my machine. If it is there any sample database to import then that is good.

Please advise.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **installer of NAV**, inside there one folder called **SQLDemoDatabase** inside. in this path `InstallerFolder\SQLDemoDatabase\CommonAppData\Microsoft\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\90\Database\Demo Database NAV (9-0).bak` It is a **backup for SQL**.

You can restore this backup and check the structure of NAV.

This applies to other versions of NAV. For you **SQL 2012** try with **NAV 2013 R2**, **NAV 2015**, NAV 2016 should work well.